Use case diagram for management system (mobile application and web-based admin panel)
I have conducted the use case diagram about Fitness Studio Mobile Application (which is the user flow) and Fitness Studio Admin Panel Website (which is about admin flow).
This is the use case diagram for the user:

This is the use case diagram for the admin:

The admin can manage the announcements, user account, packages, and others functions through the admin panel. And the user can see all the things that are posted by the admin which means that the mobile app and admin panel is interacted between each others.
What I want to ask is the use case diagram conducted correctly? Or I need to combine these two use case diagram into one will do (because my supervisor said that these two use case diagram are not acceptable)
